# How to find and replace, skipping lines containing a particular character?

Tags: bash, sed

I am using `sed` to find and replace the first appearance of an pattern in a file:

```
sed -i "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" ./file.txt
```

How can I tell it to skip any of those lines containing `{`. Here is a sample input:

```
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, so it will be changed.
```

Here is the sample output:

```
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the replacement, and not the character, so it will be changed.
```

- Only one change is made in the entire file.
- If every line with the pattern also contains `{`, then no changes are made to the file.

How can I use `sed` to find and replace the first appearance of an item, but skipping any lines that contain another pattern, in this case `{`?

Comment: you mean this? `sed -r 's/^([^{]*)pattern([^{]*)$/\1replacement\2/g' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/b;/pattern/{s//replacement/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

Skips any lines containing `{` on matching the first pattern, substitutes it for the replacement then prints remaining lines to the end-of-file.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a minor modification:

```
sed -i -e '/{/!s/pattern/replacement/' file
```

It would skip changing anything to the line (skip `s`) if line matches `/{/`. `!` negates it and allows `s`.

It's synonymous to this:

```
sed -i -e '/{/b; s/pattern/replacement/' file
```

`b` makes it skip (jumps to end).

Test:

```
# sed '/{/!s/pattern/replacement/' file
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the replacement, and not the character, so it will be changed.
```

And add `g` if you need to replace more than one pattern:

```
sed -i -e '/{/!s/pattern/replacement/g' file
```

#### Update

Using `awk`:

```
awk '!/{/ && !x { x = sub(/pattern/, "replacement") } { a[NR] = $0 }
     END { for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) print a[i] }' file
```

Input:

```
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, so it will be changed.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, so it will be changed.
```

Output:

```
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the replacement, and not the character, so it will be changed.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, so it will be changed.
```

To make changes to file directly:

```
awk '!/{/ && !x { x = sub(/pattern/, "replacement") } { a[NR] = $0 }
     END { for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) print a[i] > FILENAME }' file
```

Use `gsub` instead of `sub` to replace more than one match on the first matched line.

Comment: @Jotne Yes but sometimes I find it more beautiful having `-e` to save sed the trouble of checking if the argument is an option or an expression.

Comment: This works correctly to replace the first occurence only and not the last.

Comment: @martin What do you mean not the last?

Comment: @konsolebox look at my answer, your solution matches the first occurence in a line only, which is perfectly correct. My solution matches the last one, which seems not to be what the OP wants.

Comment: This seems to be replacing the match many times throughout the file.

Comment: @Village See my new solution with `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `awk`

```
awk '!/{/ {sub(/pattern/,"replacement")}1' file
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the replacement, and not the character, so it will be changed.
```

This replaces `pattern` with `replacement` on lines not have `{`

---

To make the change of the file (emulate `sed -i`)

```
awk '!/{/ {sub(/pattern/,"replacement")}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much more simpler with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/pattern/replacement/ unless(/\{/)' your_file
```

In place replacement:

```
perl -pi -e 's/pattern/replacement/ unless(/\{/)' your_file
```

Comment: Get an error like this `Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/pattern/replacement unless(/\" ....`

Comment: missed a forward slash. Updated and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Jotne solution for only one replacement for this file:

```
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, but another pattern.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, but is the second line.
```

is

```
awk 'BEGIN {b = 0} !/{/ && !b { b=sub(/pattern/,"replacement");}1' file
```

and gives

```
This line does not have the item, so it is skipped.
This line has the pattern, but also has {, so it is skipped too.
This line has the replacement, and not the character, but another pattern.
This line has the pattern, and not the character, but is the second line.
```

Gnu awk also has an inplace option:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN {b = 0} !/{/ && !b { b=sub(/pattern/,"replacement");}1' file
```

Comment: This seems to replace the pattern many times throughout the file.

Comment: Ah, yes, in each line. I've read your question again, you want only the first occurrence in the whole file?

Comment: Yes, just one change in the entire file.

Comment: @Village, see my modified solution.