# How to change sed '/{/b;/pattern/{s//replacement/;:a;n;ba}' so it replaces every occurance found in a file?

Tags: bash, sed

I can use `sed 's/pattern/replacement/g file.txt` to replace every occurrence of "pattern" with "replacement in `file.txt`.

According to [How to find and replace, skipping lines containing a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357801/how-to-find-and-replace-skipping-lines-containing-a-particular-character), I can use `sed '/{/b;/pattern/{s//replacement/;:a;n;ba}' file.txt` to replace the first occurrence of "pattern" with "replacement", but not when "{" is found on the line.

Where can I add "g" to `sed '/{/b;/pattern/{s//replacement/;:a;n;ba}' file.txt` so that this replaces all occurrences of "pattern" with "replacement, but not when "{" is found on the line, not just the first occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below awk command.

```
awk '!/{/{gsub(/pattern/, "replacement")}1' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `!/{/` Don't do the following function (*gsub*) on the lines which contain `{` symbol.
- `gsub(/pattern/, "replacement")` replace the string `pattern` with `replacement` globally.
- `1` Print  all the lines after processing all the  functions.

An ugly sed command.

```
sed  '/^[^\{]*$/s/pattern/replacement/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
gchg { pattern pattern
hghg pattern
pattern pattern
$ awk '!/{/{gsub(/pattern/, "replacement")}1' file
gchg { pattern pattern
hghg replacement
replacement replacement
$ sed '/^[^\{]*$/s/pattern/replacement/g' file
gchg { pattern pattern
hghg replacement
replacement replacement
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/b;/pattern/s//replacement/g' file
```

Will replace `pattern` with `replacement` except for lines containing `{`.